# running build on jenkins fails ssh-agent error

Tags: jenkins, ssh

When I run a build using a master/slave system and Jenkins, Jenkins running on a slave gives me the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
  /tmp/jffi5344372940870867938.tmp: /tmp/jffi5344372940870867938.tmp:
    failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted

FATAL: Could not find a suitable ssh-agent provider
```

On master it works perfectly.

Is there a configuration issue I am missing?

Comment: If you find a solution to your issue yourself it's perfectly fine to post it as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding the following to JVM Options (click Advanced... button when adding a slave):

```
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/jenkins/data
```